# WPF Button IsPressed and Accelerator Key Trigger

Tags: wpf

I have a button with the Text _R. When the user pressed the R key it activates. Now my button template changes the appearance via a trigger on IsPressed. This works for mouse click or SPACEBAR.
Is there a way to change the appearance the same as the IsPressed trigger when the user pressed R?
Is there some other trigger I am missing?

I noticed this from the MSDN documentation.

IsPressed is the state of a button that indicates the left mouse button or SPACEBAR is pressed over the button. When IsPressed is true, the control captures the mouse. As a result, the control will raise mouse events such as MouseEnter and IsMouseDirectlyOverChanged. Note that using the AccessText or ENTER does not change IsPressed or capture the mouse, but is does raise the Click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch Keyboard events

Add in the constructor:

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(Window), Keyboard.KeyDownEvent, new System.Windows.Input.KeyEventHandler(keyDown), true);
```

And implement the method:

```
private void keyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if ( Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.R))
    {
        // Your code
    }
}
```