# WPF How to call rendertransform or trigger a trigger

Tags: wpf

In my button's control template I have a IsPressed trigger the moves the button down and to the right. This all works great when the button is actually clicked. Now I related to my other question:
[WPF Button IsPressed and Accelerator Key Trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306030/wpf-button-ispressed-and-accelerator-key-trigger)

When the user presses a key, I want to also have my button affected with the same RenderTransform. Can I either trigger the trigger or somehow apply a new or existing transform to the button?

```
    <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed" Value="true">
    <Setter TargetName="buttonBorder" Property="RenderTransform" >
        <Setter.Value>
            <TranslateTransform Y="1.0" X="1.0" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Trigger>
```

Answer (score 0):

> When the user presses a key, I want to also have my button affected

Move the translation operation into a storyboard which can be executed from the key press as well. Change the trigger to call that storyboard instead.

```
<Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed" Value="true">
   <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource buttonBorderChange}"/>
</Trigger>
```